# Entity classes from database hangs when "retrieving the keys" from data source Netbeans/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

Inside Netbeans 8.0.2:

Steps: New File > Hibernate>  Hibernate reverse engineering

Retrieval of the Tables and Views begin, gets to 98% and then hangs.  It freezes on the same view OR the very next view.

I've tried on multiple machines - same result.

Is there a limit on the size of the input data - in the wizard?  Or, maybe a problem with the database - itself?

This is VisualVS snapshot
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One guess. Try increasing the heap size of Eclipse. Use the .ini file and increase the -Xmx and -Xms parameters. It is a pure guess, but who knows :)

Second suggestion :) You visualVM or yourkit or profiler whatever profiler you have. Then attach yourself to the Netbeans and then find out where exactly it is blocking. On which operation. Then We/You will know more about the nature of the error and how to resolve it :D

Comment: Well do the same for the Netbeans.

Comment: I was thinking about the combined stack trace to be honest. We just see that the threads are running which is not unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend clean cache dir ([details](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)), after that read this [topic](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227678) and probably you should open a bug on netbeans bugzilla.